# How helpful is learning Python to mathematicians?

Tags: soft-question, programming

> How helpful is learning Python to mathematicians, may it be pure or applied mathematicians?

I'm interested to pursue a career in mathematics. If I learn Python will it be helpful?

Comment: What kind of mathematics ?

Comment: IN any case, learning a fast growing programming language is always useful. Even if you are training to be a plumber.

Comment: @Shashank: Why not learn SAGE instead or any CAS for that matter, which has nay pure and applied mathematics in the environment?

Comment: I'm currently an undergraduate student, I'm not sure what I'm gonna do in future,but only thing I'm quite sure is I'm gonna pursue a carrer in mathematics, I was interested in python so thought of asking whether it's helpful in any way for mathematicians

Comment: Learning any programming language can help you grow as a mathematician (*and indeed, any other profession*), not just because of the additional tools and methods available to help investigate a particular topic or how to present your findings, but also because it helps you learn how to think methodically... structuring algorithms and arguments.

Comment: Python is the most enjoyable programming language in my opinion, so it is worth learning :-) . In any case, if you study algorithms for example applying them on Python can be very useful to learn them better

Comment: Could anyone also suggest some must learn programming languages for mathematicians

Comment: To my opinion, python is not very user-friendly. I prefer PARI/GP and for group theoretical purposes, GAP.

Comment: Python was very useful to me in a Numerical Analysis course I took, I don't see why not learn it considering how natural its syntax is. If you are interested in SAGE, I'd say learn both, but definitely learning some python is a good time investment.

Comment: Honestly, a lot of programming languages feel the same after a while... they just sometimes have different limitations or different libraries you often connect to them with.  There are of course exceptions... and certain languages are better geared than others for more powerful calculations.  R, MatLab, Haskell are all rather good for that.  Python is also rather good if only for the reason that there are thousands of interesting libraries readily available, giving you access to things like machine learning without having to understand the finer details and code it from scratch.

Comment: Python is also nice due to the relatively low barrier to entry.  In some other languages, it might be a bit of effort or a bit confusing to actually compile the code so it can run and it can be hard to debug without having to stop and start the whole thing again.  With Python, you have the ability to prototype your code using Jupyter Notebooks, allowing you to run code one block at a time in whatever order, and make changes on the fly... effectively letting you write the code while it is running in real time.

Comment: @JMoravitz Seems to depend on the topic. Also, programming something from the scratch might have an even better learning effect , although I certainly do not suggest to always invent the wheel new.

Comment: Sage is built on top of Python, and it's a good idea to learn Python first. When you're comfortable with core Python, and some of the standard libraries (and maybe some Numpy), you will find it very easy to start learning Sage by working through the Sage tutorial. After a day or so, you'll easily be able to do symbolic algebra & calculus in Sage. And you can even use it online, without installing anything, see the [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd just like to clarify the comment I made underneath user3716267's answer, and it seems appropriate to post it as its own separate answer.

Whether you decide to learn something like python is entirely dependent on what kind of mathematics you expect to do research in. For instance, I myself do research in homological algebra and algebraic topology, and I never ever use my own programming skills as part of my research. And unless programming tools or the understanding of those areas of mathematics change drastically, I don't expect that to change. In short, pure mathematics has very little reliance (except in very specific circumstances, such as the Four Colour Theorem) on the use of programming when it comes to research.

However, there are other PhD students in my department that *entirely* rely on python and related languages as part of their research. Those are the people studying applied mathematics. They are studying data analysis or certain areas of physics. If you expect to study applied mathematics then I *highly* recommend you learn python (or something similar, like R), in particular learn numerical methods and machine learning.

Comment: I rather disagree with the "absoluteness" of your dismissal of programming in pure maths. For example, Giles Gardam recently resolved one of [Kaplansky's conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky%27s_conjectures) (see also [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematician-disproves-group-algebra-unit-conjecture-20210412/)); he obtained the example via computer computation, although his proof is readable by hand.

Comment: @user1729 I don't think it's absolutely dismissable. As I said, it's useful in specific circumstances. But for pure mathematics it's decidedly not a ubiquitous tool for research.

Comment: You say it is "entirely dependent on what kind of mathematics you expect to do research in", which is rather absolute. If someone is good at programming and enjoys a specific subject, then mathematical research is such that their programming can likely be put to good use in advancing their subject *irregardless* of the specific subject. On the other hand, I agree that it is not ubiquitous and not *needed* for research.

Comment: @user1729 But my own programming skills are not at all relevant or useful in my own research, and I know many mathematicians in exactly the same boat. Pure mathematics simply doesn't lend itself, in many circumstances, to the implementation of code as a way of doing research. That doesn't mean I think you absolutely shouldn't learn programming if you think you're more likely to study pure mathematics, just that if you want to be efficient with your time it most likely won't end up being useful.

Comment: From my reading of your answer you're a PhD student, right? Then: research goes where you steer it. Everyone picks their own research direction based on their own skills and interests. So your first sentence should be "my own programming skills are not at all relevant or useful in my own research *so far*". If it is something you enjoy and are good at, you will surely find ways of getting it into your research (maybe not now, but in the future). [On the other hand, I have never used calculus in my research. Ever.]

Answer (score -1):

Python can be used for many purposes: numerical testing of hypotheses, [probabilistic programming](https://pyro.ai/), problems such as on [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/), et cetera. Some theorems are most readily proved computationally by exhaustion of cases; see the [Four Color Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem), for example.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it's absolutely essential for a mathematician in the modern era to know how to program.  The choice of language is mostly non-critical (Python's a fair choice).

Comment: I disagree that it's "absolutely essential". There are many areas of mathematics than can be studied to a very advanced level, as in research and beyond, that don't require the use or knowledge of programming. I think it depends on what you intend to study.

That's not to say you shouldn't learn how to program. I myself used to be a software developer, but in my day-to-day life as a mathematician I never use any sort of programming language to supplement my research.

Comment: @SeraPhim I agree.

Comment: Well how useful is quantum computing then for mathematicians?

Comment: @SeraPhim Would you not say that you understand a mathematical concept better once you have implemented it successfully in code?  I think your history as a software developer is likely an invaluable and inextricable part of your ability as a mathematician, and that any mathematician that does not learn to program is potentially robbing themselves of this.

Comment: @user3716267 it's not a question of whether you understand a concept better once it's been implemented in code, which I certainly agree with. What I'm saying is that in pure mathematics it's often impossible to implement concepts in code, especially at the level of research.

Comment: @SeraPhim Concepts that cannot themselves be directly implemented in code are still derived from, and fundamentally related to, other concepts that *can* be.  Past that, a lot of very important metamathematical results are fruitfully interpreted in the context of computability, so learning to program also helps provide an understanding of what the activity of mathematics *is*.

Comment: The absolutism in this answer is unwarranted. Programming is very useful for modern mathematical research? Yes. Programming is essential for modern mathematical research? No.

Comment: @DanRust Can you describe the sort of mathematics student that you'd advise against learning the rudiments of programming, on the grounds that it would not improve their mathematical understanding?

Comment: Again, you're arguing for usefulness, not necessity. You can have a perfectly successful career in mathematics without using a single line of code. Whether learning programming could improve said successful career is a separate matter.

Comment: Do you actually disagree with the piece of advice, or are you just quibbling over semantics?

Comment: You didn't give advice, you provided an absolute statement. I think 'quibbling over semantics' is important in this instance, lest someone read your answer and come away thinking they will fail because they can't program well or don't have the time to learn.

Comment: I'm not really buying that concern.  In practice, every single mathematician I have met has, at some point, written a line of code.  This isn't an accident.  The post says nothing about much programming one should learn...

Comment: Then you really haven't met enough mathematicians. I haven't written a single line of code in my 7 year research career in pure mathematics, and I'd say only about half of my colleagues dabble in programming.